# Type Casting Error in C, When using a function return a char value

Tags: c, function, type-conversion

I am a newbie to C Language. For a my assignment, I wrote this simple code to Print the student grade according to the input marks.

```
main(){

    char grade;
    grade = grade_calc(90);
    printf("Your Grade is ", grade);
}

char grade_calc(int marks){
    if(marks >= 75){
        return "A";
    }
    else {
        return "B";
    }
}
```

But it shows error in Function starting line (int marks).

`functions.c  [Warning] return makes integer from pointer without a cast`

Can anyone help me, why it this error happens?

Comment: you need to give printf the parameter you want to print '"Your Grade is %c", grade'

Comment: `"A"` is a string literal, not a char. Try `return 'A';` instead.

Comment: `"A"` is a ***String Literal*** while `'A'` is a ***Character Literal***.

Comment: OT: `main(){` is wrong... get a better book

Comment: And... `printf("Your Grade is ", grade);` is missing information about what you want to print. Try `printf("Your Grade is %c", grade);`

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

```c
int main(){

    char grade;
    grade = grade_calc(90);
    printf("Your Grade is %c", grade); //%c specify char
    //                    ^^
}

char grade_calc(int marks){
    if(marks >= 75){
        return 'A'; 
        //     ^ ^
    }
    else {
        return 'B';
        //     ^ ^
    }
}
```

In case you want to know more: [C format specifiers](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/format-specifiers-in-c).
Also, your return type is conflicting(`char` vs `char*`).In case you don't know, `"A"` is a `char*` (string) and `'A'` is a `char` (you can learn more about the differences [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/whats-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c/)
. Last but not least, don't forget that `main()` return `int` and functions need to be defined before used.

Comment: `return "A";` This is repeating the same mistake the OP made.

Comment: And `char grade_calc(int marks);` before `int main()` is also necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This is the declaration of printf

```
int printf(const char *format, ...)
```

printf takes the arguments (what you send to it in the parenthesis) and print it on the screen.

but, printf need to know where to print from (aka what bits you want to print), when to stop and which format are we talking about.

for example:
if we takes a int printf needs to know where is it to see its value.
which type it (int) so printf know to stop printing after 4 bytes. and again the type(int) so the bits will represent as numbers and not chars or floats

every type has its wildcard:
%d for int
%c for char
%s for strings
%f for float

you can look it up

also you need to return a char from the function
so you need to return this:

```
 return('a'); and not return ("a");
```

so,

```
 "a"
```

means string literal so the function returns `char *` and not `char`.

```
  'a'
```

means value of the char a

Comment: Also important to note, to help make sense of the error message, that a "string literal" in C is actually a pointer, a pointer to the string in memory, and that `char` is actually an integer type, an 8-bit integer.

Comment: that what i wrote    `means string literal so the function returns 'char *' and not 'char'.`

Comment: Yes, you did @AsafItach... I was just clarifying since a newbie may not understand what the asterisk means.